# Simple Jersey Hello World 404 resource not found

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

This is my project folder

http://postimg.org/image/huftiysmn/

here is the Hello.java code:

```
package ale;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    public String hello(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

and the web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
 <display-name>Ciao</display-name>
 <servlet>
  <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>ale</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

when i launch tomcat from eclipse at the URL: localhost:8080/Ciao/rest/hello, i got "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found"

i never wrote a rest application so it might be something stupid but i cant figure out what is wrong, any idea?

Comment: Not sure if it's causing the error, or if I'm right, but I don't think you need the leading slash in `/hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im kinda late but here is the solution i found:i actually solved the problem converting my project to a maven project. i think the problem was in some version mismatch between some jars in my library. @keyser after the library fix the project is working either with or without the slash in the path

Answer (score 0):

You need create @XmlRootElement

try something like this

Class hi.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class hello {

    private String hi;

    public String getHi() {
        return hi;
    }
    public void setHi(String hi) {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

}
```

Class ale.java

```
package ale;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    public String hello(){
        return getHi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of jersey dependencies in pom.xml to 1.19.4 file [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Q01.jpg).

Comment: use this format in order to embed the image. `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`